# Problem with environment variable?

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, environment-variables

When I type echo at here:

```
skyI@skyI-MP-i1640:~$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR    
/run/user/1000
```

It displays `/run/user/1000`, but when  type echo here:

```
root@skyI-MP-i1640:/SLAM/DSO/dso# echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

It does not display the `/run/user/1000`

Why and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Each user has environment variables. `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is most likely not defined in root user's environment or is being overwritten as empty.

To fix it in your current shell (temporarily), login as root and type `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"`

To fix it every time root logs in you can define it in `~root/.profile`.
Just add the line `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"` at the bottom of the file. Then either `source ~/.profile` or logout & login again.

You can verify which environment variables are defined in the current shell, type `env`, or a specific one with `env | grep XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`

Comment: While technically correct answer, I don't think it is what the requester needs, to have root using user directory. Question is why they need the variable and how it is set for regular user.

Answer (score 0):

it is solved. Sorry very simple answer.
Why: They are different user. Different users have different .bashrc files.
How: Just export like this,
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"

Comment: It seems that the solution was originally suggested in [an already existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246718/816190) to this question. Consider marking that answer as [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).